# Call two function within main function PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-performance, dynamic-sql

i have two functions one with the english language and the other with the french language. I would like to create a third function which will be the main function that will return the first function if the language = 'ang' and the second if the language = 'fr'.
how can i do that ?

see first function : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a7acc2cc946f2269a56ffea742ae3fca

see second function : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=80458461971c0722fc673de5ec763e16

Comment: Use trivial CASE in your "main" function.

Comment: can you do that here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5fc1486abf275a1f834de936b26abec8

Comment: You must specify the language as a parameter - function cannot predict your need. Like https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a40d2e625370d000d82b732f3f7552d3